# file then how to run jmeter script for load testingHow to run jmeter laod testing if add ip address in hosts?

Tags: apache, jmeter

Jmeter load testing if add ip address in hosts file.i have already tried in host file configuration

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should add [DNS Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#DNS_Cache_Manager) to your Test Plan, it has [Static Host Table](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#static_host_table) feature which can be used as the equivalent of `hosts` file manipulation on OS level

[image: JMeter DNS Cache Manager]

See [The DNS Cache Manager: The Right Way To Test Load Balanced Apps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dns-cache-manager-right-way-test-load-balanced-apps) article for more details.